# Mate Ubuntu 14.04 battery indicator not showing status

Tags: 14.04, battery, mate

I got Ubuntu 14.04 MATE. But battery indicator is not showing properly even after connecting the power cable or disconnecting. It just shows what's when started.

Image-1 when power connected:

[image]

[image]

Comment: am i right, that you mixed up your links?

Comment: maybe it takes some time to change the icons, or something changed your discharging-icon... or if you have the same problem with other DEs or OSes, it is maybe a sensor-problem!

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the "Control Center" --> "Power Management" --> "General"!
use the bullets to choose your preference!

---

if it don't acts like expected you can install the "dconf Editor" (type in terminal: `sudo apt-get install -y dconf-editor`) and have a look at the section "org" - "mate" - "power-manager" - "icon-policy"... this also changes the behavior of the battery-icon.
BUT be careful with this editor!!!

Comment: I checked it. Even if it connects or disconnects it doesn't show any changes. 

When connected the power cable,
http://postimg.org/image/htj0v6h6v/

When power cable disconnected
http://postimg.org/image/4s1pmcdeh/

Doesn't do anything

Comment: code 'upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0'

Only shows if it is connected or disconnected not in the graphical icon

Comment: dconf doesn't do anything. I tried it

Comment: it depends on the version of MATE you have installed...!

Comment: MATE Desktop Environment 1.8.1 is the version

Comment: When I asked Ubuntu mate in IRC they said my laptop doesn't support for the New Kernel Linux provides with Ubuntu 14.04 . But it was working earlier when installed. I recently updates few packages but all of sudden indicator stopped working They shared this link 
My laptop is Toshiba C640 http://linux.toshiba-dme.co.jp/linux/

Comment: I've checked it with Linux Mint (is a derivate of Ubuntu with MATE): the power-icon works as expected and also dconf is working with MATE >= 1.6.x!

Comment: so this must be a hardware-sensor-kernel-problem! - and i can't help you further because i don't have any access to a Toshiba-machine!

Comment: So in Linux mint it works and ubuntu mate doesn't. ok